# Is there a way to install a fan switch for a ceiling fan that doesn't have a fan wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Just a general question, as I was installing our new ceiling fan last night. From the ceiling, there is a white wire and a black wire (and the bare copper). I attached the two green/white wires to the bare copper, the white to white, and the black to my blue and black wires coming from the fan. This works fine, but I was really hoping to have a switch for the fan and another for the light.

Is there a way to go about this without redoing the entire wiring?

Answer (score 1):

There are remote modules you can purchase to control the light/fan separately.  Most remote modules are wireless but there are some hardwired remote modules.  I've used both but my preference is to spend the 15 dollars more and get the hardwired control.  One that I've used and liked is this one from [Lutron Maestro](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Maestro-1-Amp-Single-Pole-7-Speed-Combination-Fan-and-Light-Control-White-MA-LFQHW-WH/100576179?N=5yc1vZc32s).  It will use the single hot wire to control both the fan and light using a control module you install at the base of the fan.